# Write python function that sums values from certain rows for each index type using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my dataframe, `df`, I am trying to sum the values from the `value` column for each `Product` and `Year` for two  periods of the year (`Month`), specifically Months 1 through 3 and Months 9 through 11. I know I need to use `groupby` to group Products and Years, and possibly use a lambda function (or an if statement) to separate the two periods of time.

Here's my data frame `df`:

```py
import pandas as pd
products = {'Product': ['A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','C',
                       'C','C','C'],
            'Month': [1,1,3,4,5,10,4,5,10,11,2,3,5,3,9,
                       10,11,12],
            'Year': [1999,1999,1999,1999,1999,1999,2017,2017,1988,1988,2002,2002,2002,2003,2003,
                       2003,2003,2003],
            'value': [250,810,1200,340,250,800,1200,400,250,800,1200,300,290,800,1200,300, 1200, 300]
            }

df = pd.DataFrame(products, columns= ['Product', 'Month','Year','value'])
df
```

And I want a table that looks something like this:

```py
products = {'Product': ['A','A','B','B','C','C','C'],
            'MonthGroups': ['Month1:3','Month9:11','Month1:3','Month9:11','Month1:3','Month1:3','Month9:11'],
            'Year': [1999,1999,2017,1988,2002, 2003, 2003],
            'SummedValue': [2260, 800, 0, 1050, 1500, 800, 2700]
            }

new_df = pd.DataFrame(products, columns= ['Product', 'MonthGroups','Year','SummedValue'])
new_df
```

What I have so far that is that I should use groupby to group Product and Year. What I'm stuck on is defining the two "Month Groups": Months 1 through 3 and Months 9 through 11, which should be the sum of value per year.

```
df.groupby(['Product','Year']).value.sum().loc[lambda p: p > 10].to_frame()
```

This isn't right though because it needs to sum based on the month groups.

Comment: Do you really want those weird month ranges, or do you want it by traditional quarters?

Comment: I want those weird month ranges :) That's part of the challenge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First created new column by [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), then aggregate also by `MonthGroups` and because `groupby` by default remove rows with misisng values if column used for `by` parameter (like here `MonthGroups`) are omitted not matched groups:

```
df1 = (df.assign(MonthGroups = np.select([df['Month'].between(1,3),
                                         df['Month'].between(9,11)],
                                         ['Month1:3','Month9:11'], default=None))
         .groupby(['Product','MonthGroups','Year']).value
         .sum()
         .reset_index(name='SummedValue')
         )
print (df1)
  Product MonthGroups  Year  SummedValue
0       A    Month1:3  1999         2260
1       A   Month9:11  1999          800
2       B   Month9:11  1988         1050
3       C    Month1:3  2002         1500
4       C    Month1:3  2003          800
5       C   Month9:11  2003         2700
```

If need also `0` sum values for not matched rows:

```
df2 = df[['Product','Year']].drop_duplicates().assign(MonthGroups='Month1:3',SummedValue=0)

df1 = (df.assign(MonthGroups = np.select([df['Month'].between(1,3),
                                         df['Month'].between(9,11)], 
                                         ['Month1:3','Month9:11'], default=None))
         .groupby(['Product','MonthGroups','Year']).value
         .sum()
         .reset_index(name='SummedValue')
         .append(df2)
         .drop_duplicates(['Product','MonthGroups','Year'])
         )
print (df1)
  Product MonthGroups  Year  SummedValue
0       A    Month1:3  1999         2260
1       A   Month9:11  1999          800
2       B   Month9:11  1988         1050
3       C    Month1:3  2002         1500
4       C    Month1:3  2003          800
5       C   Month9:11  2003         2700
6       B    Month1:3  2017            0
8       B    Month1:3  1988            0
```

Answer (score 2):

A little different approach using `pd.cut`:

```
bins = [0,3,8,11]
s = pd.cut(df['Month'],bins,labels=['1:3','irrelevant','9:11'])

(df[s.isin(['1:3','9:11'])].assign(MonthGroups=s.astype(str))
.groupby(['Product','MonthGroups','Year'])['value'].sum().reset_index())
```

---

```
  Product MonthGroups  Year  value
0       A         1:3  1999   2260
1       A        9:11  1999    800
2       B        9:11  1988   1050
3       C         1:3  2002   1500
4       C         1:3  2003    800
5       C        9:11  2003   2700
```

Comment: I think you're missing a closing parentheses in your solution.

Comment: This was solutions was good because it was short, but isn't as clear as the other solution if one wants funky combinations of MonthGroups. Thanks for providing it though!